# Extra Data error HTML Javascript Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm trying to get my inputted data from the text boxes in the table in which will be turned into an array. After building this array, I need to convert it to JSON to decode in django/python and pass it along with an HTTP POST. The HTML code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getValues(){
            var arr = new Array(); //make an array
            arr = document.getElementsByName("data_from_table"); //get all of the textboxs that were populated below using django
            var newArr = new Array(); //make an array that we will transfer back to django with user edits
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                newArr.push([arr[i].value]); //push the value of that row on to the array
            }
            JSON.dumps(newArr);
            document.getElementById('list').value = JSON.stringify(newArr);
            $.post('/login/', newArr);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <h1>{{ title }} is working!</h1> --> <!-- Keeping these for debugging purposes-->
    <h1>Welcome Customer!</h1></br></br>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" value="Logout" name='logout'>Logout</button>
        <button type="submit" value="Check Out" name='checkout' onclick="getValues()">Checkout</button>
        <input type="text" id="list" name="list" style="display:none">
        </br>
    </form>       
    <form method="get">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item ID</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>How Many We Have</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>How Many?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <ul>
                        {% for table in products %}
                        <tr>
                            {% for data in table %}
                                {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 or forloop.counter0 == 1 or forloop.counter0 == 2 or forloop.counter0 == 3 %}
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" value='{{ data }}' readonly></td>
                                {% else %}
                                <td><input type="text" name="data_from_table" value=0></td>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>  
</body>
```

I get this strange error:
Extra data: line 1 column 3 - line 1 column 33 (char 2 - 32).

From research that I've done, I've found load(), loads() and dump(). I've try them and I can't seem to get them to work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong(highly possible). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Where* do you get that error: in Javascript, or Python? Exactly what code does the error refer to?

Comment: The error appears in the javascript code (<script>). Via debugging it craps out at line 13